# GA4 - Getting a wrong value from a "purchase" event (different from Universal)

Tags: tracking

On a GA4 property we sometimes receive a purchase event with a wrong value parameter. The strange thing is that the same event, on Universal Analytics, shows the correct value amount.

We applied an integration through Google Tag Manager, so that the parameters selected for the value event is the same (from the DataLayer). Additionally, we experience the value issue on "random" purchases on random days.

Did anybody get the same issue?

Apart from this, I was wondering if there is a way to change/delete/manipulate the event value parameter. I am trying through Measurement Protocol from the GA4 event builder (https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/event-builder/), but do you know a way to convert the data-hour correctly to timestamp_micros?

Thanks!
Marco